# How to remove elements from array

Tags: javascript, html

Thanks for viewing. I have a program that can create a list of user inputs. The program can add people & remove people (starting from the top). This program also limits inputs to 7.

When the limit is reached, the oldest input in the array gets erased, and then the new input is going to appear. Basically:

```
a b c d e f g
```

(a is the oldest, and the g is the newest)

Becomes:

```
b c d e f g h
```

However, even if the program can already add elements in the array, what I can't understand is that although my program has the `pop()`function to remove people, I still can't remove anyone from my list. Furthermore, the input limitations is not followed.

Is there a missing part in my code that does the problem? Thanks.

```js
var people = [7];

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("list");
  people.push(document.getElementById("input").value);
  x.innerHTML = people.join('<br/>');
}

function myFunctions() {
  var x = document.getElementById("list");
  people.pop();
  console.log(people);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <form>
    <input id="input" type=text>
    <input type=button onclick="myFunction()" value="Add" />
    <input type=button onclick="myFunctions()" value="Remove" />
  </form>

  <div id="list">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Compare the two functions, especially the last line of each. Also note that `[7]` is not an array with a maximum length of 7, it's an array literal of length one containing `7` as first element.

Comment: There's no built-in way to limit the size of an array. You need to check the array length before pushing onto it.

Comment: Why do you think you're not removing from the array? `console.log(people)` shows that the last element is being removed each time.

Comment: Tip: use better function names. It sticks.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check if it was you want?

It seems you expect that vanilla javascript variables be reactive as in vue js or react js but they don't.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
<style>
</style>
      <script>
       var people = [7];
    
        function myFunction()
        {
          if(people.length === 7) // you should check the array size
            return console.log("it can't  add more people!");

          var x = document.getElementById("list");
          people.push(document.getElementById("input").value);
          x.innerHTML = people.join('<br/>'); 
        }
        function myFunctions()
        {
          var x = document.getElementById("list");
          people.pop(); 
          x.innerHTML = people.join('<br/>'); // you should update the list
          console.log(people);
        }
      </script>
<body>
     <form>
      <input id="input" type=text>
       <input type=button onclick="myFunction()" value="Add"/>
       <input type=button onclick="myFunctions()" value="Remove"/>
      </form>
    
     <div id="list"> 
      </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you remember the definition of index, but an array list of 7 is supposed to be [6], as the corresponding index to every variable in the list starts with 0 instead of 1.

Try to update your list before you go straight to console.log!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).